Incorrect font display in console vs code
The font is displayed incorrectly. I tried different settings in the terminal, nothing helps, I restarted the PC, vs code, changed the font size, family, but everything remains the same :( Tried changing JSON font settings
tried restarting vs code, rebooting pc, changing font family, size, thickness, distance
enter image description here
enter image description here

It's not clear from your question, but you're talking about the Terminal window in VS code and not the console.

Have you tried adjusting File->Preferences->Settings->Window->Zoom Level?  It should be 0.

Yes, it's powershell opened in vs code

I'll add another screen

Zoom level 0, too

I solved this problem. It is necessary to open the control panel of Nvidia, go to the 3D parameters management, choose Visual Studio Code and turn off FXAA:


Would have been much more useful in English.
